# Ввод кавычек с клавиатуры

Tags: unicode, клавиатура

Как ввести вот эту кавычку с клавиатуры?

> `

Какой unicode для этого есть?

Для инфы: это не обычная кавычка `'`

Answer (score 6):

Обычно она (backtick) по умолчанию на тильде (где обычно буква Ё в русской раскладке) висит в раскладке US.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а так в уникоде это `U+0060`.

Comment: чтобы набрать `U+0060` (если клавиша сломалась), [можно в Ubuntu (GTK+) набрать`Ctrl+Shift+U 60 Enter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_X11_.28Linux_and_other_Unix_variants.29).

Comment: @jfs можно проще alt+96.............alt+ 96 = `  ....Alt + 0180 = ´  ....... Alt + 39 = '

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, проще клавиатуру поменять.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский alt+96 не работает для меня.